# How to make in app subscription in react native in iap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

How do i make subscription in react native in app purchase library. It seems the library has been updated and my code only returns available subscriptions with a subscriptionOfferDetails property. I don't see the base subscription details and prices. This is my code:

```js
 
  const fetchSubscriptions = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await getSubscriptions({ skus: myProducts });
      setSubscriptions(response);
        console.log(response);
    const isPageUnlocked = response.length > 0;
    if (isPageUnlocked) {
      // Perform actions to unlock the page
      Alert.alert('Success', 'Page unlocked!');
      setShowads(false);
    } else {
      // Show message indicating no available purchases
     setShowads(true);
      Alert.alert('Error', 'My dear, No available subscription to unlock the page.');
    }


    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching subscriptions: ', error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Would love to know if you figured this out. I'm having difficulty understanding how to manage subscriptions and restore purchases using this library.